# Linker error _memcmp VS2015 upgrade in c++ project

Tags: c++, visual-c++, com, visual-studio-2015, linker-errors

I have a c++ project which I am upgrading from VS2010 to VS2015. It is a COM dll which has some COM interfaces(of course they are defined in a .idl file). The module works fine in Visual Studio 2010

I am getting the error in midl generated proxy file in side XXXXX_IID_Lookup function asking _memcmp unresolved external symbol. Now I have searched on the site and I have checked these conditions

- "Ignore All default libraries" is disabled.
- memcmp call in my source file does not gives any error.
- I have played with intrinsic(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tzkfha43.aspx) pragma, but I was not able to resolve the issue
- Although it is not relevant, I should say I have disabled "Treat warning as error" settings

Comment: Are you getting an error or a warning? From the compiler or the linker? Could you please post the message exactly as it's displayed?

Comment: I am getting a linker error - LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _memcmp referenced in function __D950Status_IID_Lookup@8

The interface name is ID950Status and the function is defined in D950Status_p.c which is generated by midl.

Comment: That's completely different from what you said in your question (*"un-referenced external symbol"*). Please [update](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/36575477/edit) your question and make sure that it is accurate.